# is there any common platform for all mobile applications?

Tags: mobile

i want to know if there is any tool or a platform for developing applications that could be run on all sort of mobiles.

that is, i want to develop an application on a platfrom which enables me to use it in Windows Mobile, Iphone, Android, Symbian OS phones .....etc

(mostly for iphone and android other are optional)

please let me know..

Comment: No (There is even no common power charger for mobile phones before 2012.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are a couple of tools for to do that. Try to "google" u will get all the info u need.

try searching for **Appcelarotor**.

Answer (score 0):

There are frameworks like Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

For native development,there is a framework base on c++:
https://github.com/9miao/CrossApp

or you would like some web-like/based framework:
https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui

further,you could google "react.js mobile"

Answer (score 0):

Try [Codename One](http://codenameone.com). It's quite new but has a lot of slick features and it allows you to use one codebase for IOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows, Web and even Javascript.